# Images stored in database are cut/cropped when displayed on browser

Tags: database, image, cut

I am trying to display images from a mysql database. Some of the images display correctly, but some appear as cut/cropped at the bottom and the cropped section just shows as whitespace, which you really can't get rid off as it becomes part of the image.

CSS can't solve this and recreating the images on the go with imagecreate etc won't restore it. I have my meta tags set to utf-8. From what I have read, this might have something to do with the utf-8 bom or so. I basically use file_get_contents or fopen and fread to get the images and store them in the database and output them using header() or base64_encode. However I do it, I get the same result.

This is the basic output image code to browser:

```
//html form
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='image' size='10'>
<input type='submit' name='submit_image' value='Upload' />
</form> 

//table creation
$my_photos = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos (
id bigint NOT NULL auto_increment,
pic blob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB";

if (mysql_query($my_photos)){
print "Success in photo TABLE creation!";
} else {
print "no photos TABLE created. Debug code!";
}

//get image
$uploaded_image = $_FILES['image'];
$image_tmp = $uploaded_image['tmp_name'];    
$image = file_get_contents($image_tmp); 

//connect and submit image to database
mysql_connect("server","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO photos (id, pic) values ('', '".$image."') "); 

//get image from database and output it
$image_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE id=1 ");
$image = mysql_fetch_array($image_query);   
header("Content-type: image/jpg/jpeg/gif/png/bmp/JPG");    
echo $image['pic'];
```

Has anyone had a similar problem and how did they fix it?

(I do use the file system for some images in my app, but need blob for this case).

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: show the create table statement? and more php code where the photo is uploaded in the database? and using the database with a blob column too store large binary data is a real performance killer for MySQL

Comment: Thanks Raymond for the quick reply. Added some more code, hopefully that helps

Comment: And your defuald charset in mysql is latin1 or utf8?

Comment: The default is utf8_general_ci

Comment: Ok iam still missing the html where the form is build up.

Comment: Thanks,just added that right above the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Handling UTF-8 data from a web client is hard in PHP you need to do alot of things.

first you need to make sure if your html page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

is in your webpage

Change your

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

to

add accept-charset=UTF-8 isn't be correcly shown here see the edit of this post to see the html code..

If this is php generated also add

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

on top

After you connect with database run directly after

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8')
```

To tell the php mysql client to use UTF-8 and not latin1 for the connection.

and i think that you need to save the photo as a base64_encoded string to keep the data correct.

Some extra side notes to fix

1) Don't use mysql_ annymore but mysqli_
2) Html code change the (') to (") in html attributs

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I had actually tried all of that without much success except for the accept-charset='UFT-8' in the form. But it seems that won't make much difference if it is already set in the  meta tags. Funny the problem isn't going away at all. What I do not seem to understand is why it works for some images, but doesn't for others.

Comment: Hey Raymond, just tried the easiest solution, which I should have in the first place. Learnt a lot from it though, after days of research etc. I just needed to change the blob to mediumblob or longblob. Guess the characters were too much for blob. Interesting that even some bigger image sizes had no problem which made me quickly rule  out file size.

Comment: if you work with uft8 you should always follow the steps what i talked about. true blob can also store a couble of bytes when stored in utf8. because you need to divide the max bytes / 3 because utf8 could store a char in three byte.